# Why can I mirror my iPad on my Mac but not use the same iPad as an extension display to my MacBook M2 (2022)?

Tags: mac, ipad, ventura, sidecar

Both devices are in the same wifi and I would love to use the iPad (8th gen, software version 15.5) as an additional screen to the Mac (OS 13.3) but when I go into settings, I cannot find the sidecar setting to turn this on.

Conversely, mirroring the iPad on the Mac works flawlessly.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sidecar "only appears if you’re using your iPad as a second display." See: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlca6faa13/13.0/mac/13.5 and https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlf3c6f7ae/13.0/mac/13.0 If you have already worked through those instructions, please expand your question with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

For me it started working after I signed into FaceTime and Messages on my iPad.

Comment: Hey! Could you please explain how this solved the problem exactly? I have used this feature without FaceTime or Messages enabled in iCloud and it worked. Did you do something else that would have solved the issue possibly?

Comment: After I did that it started working, before that i tried a bunch of other steps but non worked. I tried connecting via cable and trusting mac on ipad and vice versa, bluetooth/wifi on/off, checked that I'm logged in to same iCloud acc with 2FA etc, and nothing.

Comment: I solved mine with an IOS update?